# How to make a burndown chart in LibreOffice-calc?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I've been struggling with creating a burndown chart for scrum using LibreOffice-calc.

Can someone explain me the basic concepts, and how to plot the chart?

Answer (score 1):

> A **[burn down chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burn_down_chart)** is a graphical representation of work left to do
>   versus time. The outstanding work (or backlog) is often on the
>   vertical axis, with time along the horizontal. That is, it is a run
>   chart of outstanding work. It is useful for predicting when all of the
>   work will be completed. It is often used in agile software development
>   methodologies such as Scrum. However, burn down charts can be applied
>   to any project containing measurable progress over time. Outstanding
>   work can be represented in terms of either time or story points

~ [From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burn_down_chart)

You will likely want either a [candlestick](https://help.libreoffice.org/Chart/Chart_Type_Stock) (aka. stock chart), a [line chart](https://help.libreoffice.org/Chart/Chart_Type_Line), or [choose yourself](https://help.libreoffice.org/Chart/Choosing_a_Chart_Type).

Comment: Thanks, that was a usefull explanation. There is a good tutorial on plotting charts in libreoffice-calc? The one on wiki is nothing but a stub.

Answer (score -1):

A burn down chart is a simple graph used to track a team’s progress and help estimate how much time is required to complete the project. 
Can read more about burndown charts here.. https://www.scrumstudy.com/blog/cumulative-flow-diagrams-versus-burn-down-charts/